# Add username to solspace user password_reset_email_template

Tags: solspace-user

Anyone know if its poss to add the username to the password_reset_email_template in solspace users exp:user:forgot_password form?

Have lots of users forgetting their username as well their password so adding it to the reminder email would be handy.